# Selecting geometry from PostGIS compatible with Open3D

Tags: python, postgis, geometry

I have a cube stored as geometry in a PostGIS DB.
I get the coordinates using the following SQL:

```sql
select ST_AsEWKT(geom) from polyhedral.vol_1 where id = 1
```

This presents the following result.

```sql
POLYHEDRALSURFACE(
  ((0 1 0,0 0 0,1 0 0,1 1 0,0 1 0)),
  ((1 -0 1,0 0 1,0 1 1,1 1 1,1 -0 1)),
  ((1 0 0,1 -0 1,1 1 1,1 1 0,1 0 0)),
  ((0 0 0,0 0 1,1 -0 1,1 0 0,0 0 0)),
  ((0 1 0,0 1 1,0 0 1,0 0 0,0 1 0)),
  ((0 1 1,0 1 0,1 1 0,1 1 1,0 1 1))
)
```

would like to use this within the Open3D library.
For `.ply` files it is simple `mesh = read_triangle_mesh(filename.ply)`

Any ideas about how I would get the PostGIS output to be compatible with Open3D?

---

Using the PostGIS python library I can get the result above into python like this.

```py
conn = <connection details>
cur = conn.cursor()
print("connected")
cur.execute('SELECT ST_AsEWKT(geom) FROM polyhedral.vol_1 LIMIT 1')
geom = cur.fetchone()[0]
geom
```

---

This parses the query result into a pandas dataframe

```py
s = geom.replace('POLYHEDRALSURFACE', '')
s = s.replace("((","|")
s = s.replace("))","|")
s = s.replace(")","")
s = s.replace("|,|",",")
s = s.replace("|","",1)
s = s.replace("(","")
s = s.replace(s[len(s)-1], '')
s = s.replace(",",";")
s = s.replace(" ",",")

test = s.split(";")

df = pd.DataFrame([sub.split(",") for sub in test], columns=['x','y','z'])
```

Comment: Psycopg2 is a python library to connect to a PostgreSQL database. Many python interfaces can read from file objects or strings (it is also possible through the io modul, to read a string like a file), but i don't know about open3D.

Comment: Yes, I've been using psycopg2 a lot in other projects, I've added some example code, but the result doesn't come through in a python way. Even getting it into numpy would be a start.

Comment: Your cursor returns a string, you'll have to parse it. This may be easier with a json format (ST_AsGeoJSON), which can be used with the json-Module to make a python dict or list.

Comment: That would be logical, however `ERROR:  lwgeom_to_geojson: 'PolyhedralSurface' geometry type not supported`

Comment: @SpatialDigger you are right. `ST_AsGeoJSON()` will only work if you cast your Polyhedral to a `TIN` using `ST_Tesselate()`. Which basically breaks your polyhedral into simple triangles. Then you will be able to build a GeoJSON.